# gdal2tiles for both raster and vectors with a directory of input files (shps and .tifs)

Tags: gdal2tiles

I am looking to tile a large dataset that was split into raster areas based on political borders (ie. 1 raster file for each area). I have a few hundred .tiffs and shapefiles for the area and am trying to find the easiest way to tile them rapidly without needing to merge them first (would be an unruly large .tiff and .shp) likely why they were originally split. I have to do this for both datasets the large series of .tif's and the .shps.

I have tried QTiles but it runs incredibly slowly on a high end machine for tile generation and am hoping to use something like gdal2tile_parrelel but it doesnt work through a directory. Anyone had a similiar struggle and find a solution?

machine is i7-7700k, 64gb ram and Raid 0 drives.

Comment: build a vrt and use gdal on that? where do the shapefiles come into this?

Comment: sorry i have two datasets, one as shapefiles the other as .tiffs need to do the same for both - i will try a VRT thats a good idea

Comment: If `gdal2tile` in principal does the job, you could write a loop for it, which runs through your directory and executes it for each file. For example, you could use Python's `subprocess` for this